# Configuring rustup for visual studio 2017 using the rust extension for vs 2017

Tags: visual-studio, rust, visual-studio-2017

I have installed the Rust extension and have opened a rust project.Now in Tools>Rust where am I supposed to find the rustup.exe file.Actually I found rustup.exe in .cargo>bin folder but I dont think this is the one, i added that but vs 2017 gives the message that"could not start rls:rustup is not installed or not the path".Also what should I add in toolchain section if i want stable toolchain.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it to your `PATH` environment variable for VS to see it.

In PowerShell:

```
$rustup = '/path/to/folder/containing/rustup'

$path = (
    @([Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', 'Machine').Split(';')) + $rustup
) -join ';'

[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', $path, 'Machine')
```

You can change the target from `'Machine'` to `'User'` if you don't have elevated privileges.

Comment: @DebjitChowdhury Did you restart VS before retrying?  And did you use the rustup containing folder? not a fully-qualified path to the executable?

Comment: Yes but I still think that there has to be something to do with the path to rustup.exe through the visual studio tools option. Actually I am not having a clear idea about where it can be.